# spec run the same set of tests with different configuration

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

Assume a spec file that contains a number of tests:

```
before(:all) do
   @object = buildObjectA
end

it 'should compute x correctly' do
   test something based on object
end

it 'should compute y correctly' do
   test something based on object
end
```

I wanted to do the same set of tests but with a different configuration, for example, in before(:all), it looks like this:

```
before(:all) do
   @object = buildObjectB
end
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Shared Examples and Contexts](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.4/rspec-core/#Shared_Examples_and_Contexts):

```
RSpec.shared_examples "something" do |x|
  it 'should compute x correctly' do
    test something based on object
  end

  it 'should compute y correctly' do
    test something based on object
  end
end

RSpec.describe "A" do
  include_examples "something", buildObjectA
end

RSpec.describe "B" do
  include_examples "something", buildObjectB
end
```

(given your tests are all the same for both objects)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use `context`. Is is just like `describe` but has a more semantic name which better fits a situation like yours.

```
context 'when object is A' do
  before(:all) do
    @object = buildObjectA
  end

  it 'should compute x correctly' do
    test something based on object
  end

  it 'should compute y correctly' do
    test something based on object
  end
end

context 'when object is B' do
  before(:all) do
    @object = buildObjectB
  end

  it 'should compute x correctly' do
    test something based on object
  end

  it 'should compute y correctly' do
    test something based on object
  end
end
```

When your test fails, it will chain all `describe`, `context` and `it` arguments and give you the full description of your test example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But since all the test codes, e.g., within `it 'should computer ...'` are exactly the same. Is there a way to make it simpler (reuse that part of codes)?

Comment: Have you considered testing both objects in the same test example?

Comment: Although debatable, I wouldn't worry too much about DRY-ing specs. After all, when something fails, you just want to look at the spec and instantly understand why it's failing without having to look around trying to follow the code.